# Are electron-builder artifacts necessary in a repo?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

When publishing a build using electron-builder, a number of artifacts are created in GitHub releases in addition to .zip, .dmg, etc files:

```
latest-mac.json
latest-mac.yml
<app>.dmg.blockmap
```

Are these necessary for future auto-update detection? Is there a reason to suppress them?

Answer (score 0):

These files are used to check for Blockmap attributes, version, SHA check and also if your app is for multiple OS System.

Depending if you use Pre-release and Release it can also provide specific point for an user install beta or final release.

If your check electron-builder docs you will see:

> - zip target for macOS is required for Squirrel.Mac, otherwise
>     latest-mac.yml cannot be created, which causes autoUpdater error.
>     Default target for macOS is dmg+zip, so there is no need to explicitly
>     specify target.
> - Staged rollouts are controlled by manually editing your latest.yml /
>     latest-mac.yml (channel update info file).
> - latest.yml (or latest-mac.yml for macOS, or latest-linux.yml for
>     Linux) will be generated and uploaded for all providers except bintray
>     (because not required, bintray doesn't use latest.yml).

So, it's good to keep these files in your artifact release.